# Javascript history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, history

I found example of history.pushState() through stackoverflow but I don't understand what each thing does. this is what I have

```
var stateObj = {
    foo: "bar"
};
history.pushStates(stateObj, "page 2", "page2.html");
```

so can anyone explain what stateObj holds and what "page 2" is in this script? Why does the object have foo: "bar"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this link might be of use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method

the first parameter, `stateObj` in the example, is an arbitrary context object containing whatever you'd like.  It's accessed when the user visits a different page and then navigates back to your page using their browser's Back button.  see the `popState` event for more information there.

the second paramater is currently unused; it's recommended to pass the empty string here.

the last parameter is the URL associated with the context object.  It does not change the location of the current page.

Comment: and FYI, this is not specific to jQuery.

Comment: so what can be instead of `foo: "bar"` and what does it do there?

Comment: any data that you might want to store to access later during the popstate event.

Comment: that depends on your application!  Put some important variables in there so that if the user navigates away from your page and then goes back to it, they can pick up right where they left off.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method

Comment: Please try to expand on your answer.

Comment: @vcsjones How so? OP basically asked for documentation, which I linked to.